# Using PHP functions to validate a form

Tags: php, html, forms, function, validation

The following code worked perfectly before I put them into functions but I cannot figure out how to get this form to work correctly using the functions I created. I know I need to pass variables and create some proper main logic but I really don't know where to go from here. The end product should look something like this form: [guestbookonescript](http://professorgustin.com/dpr206/guestbook/guestbookonescript.php)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<title>Guestbook</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<?php

function check(){
$userErr = $emailErr = $noteErr = "";
$user = $email = $note = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["user"])) 
        $userErr = "Please fill out a name.";
    else 
        $user = $_POST["user"];

    if (empty($_POST["email"]))  
        $emailErr = "Please fill out an email.";
    else 
        $email = $_POST["email"];

    if (empty($_POST["note"]))  
        $noteErr = "Please give us your comments.";
    else 
    $note= $_POST["note"];



}
}       


function display(){
print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Please Sign Our Guestbook</h2>
<form method="post" action="mock.php"> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="user" value=""  /><span     class="error"><br> $userErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="email" value=""  /><span     class="error"><br> $emailErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">Comments: </td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="note">   </textarea><span class="error"><br> $noteErr</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}

function result(){
print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Your Input:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>$user</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Email: </td><td>$email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valgin="top">Comments: </td><td>$note</td>
</tr>
</table>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))

    check();
else
    display();
    result();




?>



</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors of any kind? What is the output?

Comment: You should escape your outputs better, otherwise you're vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: There are many things wrong here, but mostly you have completely failed to understand how to use functions. Take a look at the [PHP reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php). Think of a function as a closed box: you put stuff in on one side (your arguments) and something comes out of the other (your return value). There generally should be no other way of placing something into the function or getting it out. Do not be seduced by the apparent convenience of `global` variables: there lies the way of madness.

Comment: When the submit button is pressed, no information is taken from the form and submitted to the "Your Input" page. I'm not sure why, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my functions. The output can be found here: http://awsymposium.com/mock.php

Answer (score 1):

What Alon is trying to say is that all of your variables are caught in the local scope, to avoid this, you need tell the offending variables that they belong in the global scope. Technically, you don't need to initialize them first, but it's good practice.

Note, you need to ensure that your variables are in the global scope in *each* function you're using them in.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<title>Guestbook</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<?php

$userErr = $emailErr = $noteErr = "";
$user = $email = $note = "";

function check(){

    global $user, $email, $note;
    global $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr;


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["user"])) 
            $userErr = "Please fill out a name.";
        else 
            $user = $_POST["user"];

        if (empty($_POST["email"]))  
            $emailErr = "Please fill out an email.";
        else 
            $email = $_POST["email"];

        if (empty($_POST["note"]))  
            $noteErr = "Please give us your comments.";
        else 
            $note = $_POST["note"];

    }
}       


function display(){

    global $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr;

print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Please Sign Our Guestbook</h2>
<form method="post" action="/"> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="user" value=""  /><span     class="error"><br> $userErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="email" value=""  /><span     class="error"><br> $emailErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">Comments: </td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="note">   </textarea><span class="error"><br> $noteErr</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}

function result(){

    global $user, $email, $note;

print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Your Input:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>$user</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Email: </td><td>$email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valgin="top">Comments: </td><td>$note</td>
</tr>
</table>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))    
    check();

display();
result();

?>

</body>
```

Comment: I know this isn't the best way to do things, but it addresses the OP question.

Comment: That actually helped alot thanks. The results field is being populated now, but my error messages aren't popping up when a field is left empty. What can I do about that?

Comment: Hi user, because there's a gap between your textarea tags: `<textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="note">   </textarea>` Your empty check is finding three "space" characters

Answer (score -1):

You need to define variables that was declared outside the function as global. Put this line at start of your function, after `function result(){`

```
global $user,$email,$note;
```

note that variables declared inside the function scope will be deleted after the function execution. you need to declare `$user,$email,$note` ouside `check()` (and just declare them as global inside `check()`)

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. But I just tried your advice and it was, unfortunately, to no avail.

Comment: `global` variables are not the solution here, nor, generally, to any problem involving passing data into a function. The real solution here is to restructure the function with appropriate inputs & outputs.

Comment: @MikeW actually, it is  a possible solution in this case. yes, he can also pass by reference. what's your point?

Comment: `global` variables might work, but that doesn't make them a solution. In general, `global` variables lead to confused and unreadable code and they should be avoided.

Comment: @MikeW This is a valid solution for a beginner that don't know anything about functions. I agree that global varibles is not a best practice, but they are still a valid solution in PHP and specifically in the code in this question

Comment: Of course I'd prefer a more proper solution. But, as Alon said, I am a beginner and I'm just now learning about functions which are, admittedly, confusing me.